# merging two class properties while serialization using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Consider these classes:

```
public class A {
  private String a;
  private B b;
}

public class B {
  private String b1;
  private String b2;
}
```

Is there a way to serialize an object of A using Jackson, without using a custom serializer, so that the result is:

```
{"a":"aaa", "b1":"bbb1", "b2":"bbb2"}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [@JsonUnwrapped](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) on field

> Annotation used to indicate that a property should be serialized "unwrapped"; that is, if it would be serialized as JSON Object, its properties are instead included as properties of its containing Object.

```
public class A {

     private String a;

     @JsonUnwrapped
     private B b;
}

public class B {

     private String b1;

     private String b2;

}
```